# how to grab data within a table using selenium Webdriver(java)?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

now I want to use selenium webdriver to grab data from a website. Now I can log in and go to the main page. There is a table, and I would like to click each name() under the col "first name" so I could go to each client's profile for deeper search. I would like to use a list to grab each user first. Here is my code:

```
WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.id("ember2185"));


    List<WebElement> list = (List<WebElement>) table.findElement(By.className("ember-view vertical-item"));
             for (WebElement w : list) {
                 System.out.println(w);
             }
```

Here is the html inspect:

```
<vertical-collection id="ember2185" class="ember-view">
<div id="ember2236" class="ember-view vertical-item" style="min-height: 76px;">                          <div id="ember2256" class="ember-view row-patient list-item"><div class="col-pic"><img id="ember2265" src="assets/images/default_profile-51d6b94248e500ae7f03bc28a8110e4d.png" class="ember-view"></div>
<div class="row" data-guid="fad3e8d7-fb46-48a0-9e31-fd5577c17bab">
    <div class="col-name">
        <div data-element="patient-first-name"><p class="p-link">Cindy <!----><!----></p></div>
        <div data-element="patient-record-number" class="prn"><span class="p-666">PRN </span><span>CO711603</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-name">
        <div data-element="patient-last-name"><p class="p-link">DemoObstetrics</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-small">
        <div id="ember2274" data-element="patient-dob" class="ember-view"><div class="visible-xs visible-sm">01/14/1982</div>
<div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">Jan 14, 1982</div>
</div>
        <div data-element="patient-gender">Female</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-contact">
        <div data-element="patient-address" class="ellipses" title="312 S 67th St,, Schenectady, NY 12345">312 S 67th St,, Schenectady, NY 12345</div>
        <div data-element="patient-phone-numbers" class="ellipses">
            <span id="ember2283" title="(555) 555-5555" class="ember-view phone-number"><span class="p-666">M </span>
<span>(555) 555-5555</span></span>
            <span id="ember2284" title="(555) 555-5555" class="ember-view phone-number"><span class="p-666">H </span>
<span>(555) 555-5555</span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-small text-right" data-element="patient-last-accessed">
        <div>6:02 PM</div>
        <div>04/23/18</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>


</div><div id="ember2237" class="ember-view vertical-item" style="min-height: 76px;">                          <div id="ember2285" class="ember-view row-patient list-item"><div class="col-pic"><img id="ember2286" src="assets/images/default_profile-51d6b94248e500ae7f03bc28a8110e4d.png" class="ember-view"></div>
<div class="row" data-guid="dd2308fa-01cb-4bc2-a0f1-abc08ff792c9">
    <div class="col-name">
        <div data-element="patient-first-name"><p class="p-link">Michelle <!----><!----></p></div>
        <div data-element="patient-record-number" class="prn"><span class="p-666">PRN </span><span>MG875244</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-name">
        <div data-element="patient-last-name"><p class="p-link">DemoGyn</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-small">
        <div id="ember2287" data-element="patient-dob" class="ember-view"><div class="visible-xs visible-sm">05/16/1955</div>
<div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">May 16, 1955</div>
</div>
        <div data-element="patient-gender">Female</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-contact">
        <div data-element="patient-address" class="ellipses" title="123 S. 45th St., Anytown, NY 12345">123 S. 45th St., Anytown, NY 12345</div>
        <div data-element="patient-phone-numbers" class="ellipses">
            <span id="ember2288" title="(555) 555-5555" class="ember-view phone-number"><span class="p-666">M </span>
<span>(555) 555-5555</span></span>
            <span id="ember2289" title="(555) 555-5555" class="ember-view phone-number"><span class="p-666">H </span>
<span>(555) 555-5555</span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-small text-right" data-element="patient-last-accessed">
        <div>1:32 PM</div>
        <div>04/18/18</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>


</div><div id="ember2238" class="ember-view vertical-item" style="min-height: 76px;">                          <div id="ember2290" class="ember-view row-patient list-item"><div class="col-pic"><img id="ember2291" src="assets/images/default_profile-51d6b94248e500ae7f03bc28a8110e4d.png" class="ember-view"></div>
<div class="row" data-guid="477f5a0d-04e6-410b-afc6-adbacb55af99">
    <div class="col-name">
        <div data-element="patient-first-name"><p class="p-link">Eric <!----><!----></p></div>
        <div data-element="patient-record-number" class="prn"><span class="p-666">PRN </span><span>EG629610</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-name">
        <div data-element="patient-last-name"><p class="p-link">DemoGastro</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-small">
        <div id="ember2292" data-element="patient-dob" class="ember-view"><div class="visible-xs visible-sm">05/12/1951</div>
<div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">May 12, 1951</div>
</div>
        <div data-element="patient-gender">Male</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-contact">
        <div data-element="patient-address" class="ellipses" title="3278 Maple St., San Antonio, TX 78023">3278 Maple St., San Antonio, TX 78023</div>
        <div data-element="patient-phone-numbers" class="ellipses">
            <span id="ember2293" title="(555) 555-5555" class="ember-view phone-number"><span class="p-666">M </span>
<span>(555) 555-5555</span></span>
            <span id="ember2294" title="(555) 555-5555" class="ember-view phone-number"><span class="p-666">H </span>
<span>(555) 555-5555</span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-small text-right" data-element="patient-last-accessed">
        <div>1:30 PM</div>
        <div>04/18/18</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>


</div><div id="ember2239" class="ember-view vertical-item" style="min-height: 76px;">                          <div id="ember2295" class="ember-view row-patient list-item"><div class="col-pic"><img id="ember2296" src="assets/images/default_profile-51d6b94248e500ae7f03bc28a8110e4d.png" class="ember-view"></div>
<div class="row" data-guid="e6bd1691-db04-4bfc-be72-1acc590cb93e">
    <div class="col-name">
        <div data-element="patient-first-name"><p class="p-link">Jennifer <!----><!----></p></div>
        <div data-element="patient-record-number" class="prn"><span class="p-666">PRN </span><span>JR572205</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-name">
        <div data-element="patient-last-name"><p class="p-link">DemoRheum</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-small">
        <div id="ember2297" data-element="patient-dob" class="ember-view"><div class="visible-xs visible-sm">03/05/1970</div>
<div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">Mar 05, 1970</div>
</div>
        <div data-element="patient-gender">Female</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-contact">
        <div data-element="patient-address" class="ellipses" title="45 Deer Run Road, Livingston, NJ 07039">45 Deer Run Road, Livingston, NJ 07039</div>
        <div data-element="patient-phone-numbers" class="ellipses">
            <span id="ember2298" title="(555) 555-5555" class="ember-view phone-number"><span class="p-666">M </span>
<span>(555) 555-5555</span></span>
            <span id="ember2299" title="(555) 555-5555" class="ember-view phone-number"><span class="p-666">H </span>
<span>(555) 555-5555</span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-small text-right" data-element="patient-last-accessed">
        <div>10:51 PM</div>
        <div>04/17/18</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>


</div><div id="ember2240" class="ember-view vertical-item" style="min-height: 76px;">                          <div id="ember2300" class="ember-view row-patient list-item"><div class="col-pic"><img id="ember2301" src="assets/images/default_profile-51d6b94248e500ae7f03bc28a8110e4d.png" class="ember-view"></div>
<div class="row" data-guid="a6547f58-1af7-404d-8896-e95cd8ec2bd1">
    <div class="col-name">
        <div data-element="patient-first-name"><p class="p-link">Michael T<!----></p></div>
        <div data-element="patient-record-number" class="prn"><span class="p-666">PRN </span><span>MO686770</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-name">
        <div data-element="patient-last-name"><p class="p-link">DemoPrimaryCare</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-small">
        <div id="ember2302" data-element="patient-dob" class="ember-view"><div class="visible-xs visible-sm">07/05/1958</div>
<div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">Jul 05, 1958</div>
</div>
        <div data-element="patient-gender">Male</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-contact">
        <div data-element="patient-address" class="ellipses" title="5432 Rebrow St, Lakeside, NY 27511">5432 Rebrow St, Lakeside, NY 27511</div>
        <div data-element="patient-phone-numbers" class="ellipses">
            <span id="ember2303" title="(555) 555-5555" class="ember-view phone-number"><span class="p-666">M </span>
<span>(555) 555-5555</span></span>
            <span id="ember2304" title="(555) 555-5555" class="ember-view phone-number"><span class="p-666">H </span>
<span>(555) 555-5555</span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-small text-right" data-element="patient-last-accessed">
        <div>10:51 PM</div>
        <div>04/17/18</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>


</div><div id="ember2241" class="ember-view vertical-item" style="min-height: 76px;">                          <div id="ember2305" class="ember-view row-patient list-item"><div class="col-pic"><img id="ember2306" src="assets/images/default_profile-51d6b94248e500ae7f03bc28a8110e4d.png" class="ember-view"></div>
<div class="row" data-guid="ce433b32-0ff7-4e42-b569-b1e7b8607524">
    <div class="col-name">
        <div data-element="patient-first-name"><p class="p-link">Eric R<!----></p></div>
        <div data-element="patient-record-number" class="prn"><span class="p-666">PRN </span><span>EP108956</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-name">
        <div data-element="patient-last-name"><p class="p-link">DemoPsych</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-small">
        <div id="ember2307" data-element="patient-dob" class="ember-view"><div class="visible-xs visible-sm">03/01/1965</div>
<div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">Mar 01, 1965</div>
</div>
        <div data-element="patient-gender">Male</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-contact">
        <div data-element="patient-address" class="ellipses" title="783 Washington Ave, Hollytown, NH 33220">783 Washington Ave, Hollytown, NH 33220</div>
        <div data-element="patient-phone-numbers" class="ellipses">
            <span id="ember2308" title="(555) 555-5555" class="ember-view phone-number"><span class="p-666">M </span>
<span>(555) 555-5555</span></span>
            <span id="ember2309" title="(555) 555-5555" class="ember-view phone-number"><span class="p-666">H </span>
<span>(555) 555-5555</span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-small text-right" data-element="patient-last-accessed">
        <div>10:51 PM</div>
        <div>04/17/18</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>


</div><div id="ember2242" class="ember-view vertical-item" style="min-height: 76px;">                          <div id="ember2310" class="ember-view row-patient list-item"><div class="col-pic"><img id="ember2311" src="assets/images/default_profile-51d6b94248e500ae7f03bc28a8110e4d.png" class="ember-view"></div>
<div class="row" data-guid="4c54bc81-a6df-4409-9312-aef3ba6ed2ed">
    <div class="col-name">
        <div data-element="patient-first-name"><p class="p-link">Steve <!----><!----></p></div>
        <div data-element="patient-record-number" class="prn"><span class="p-666">PRN </span><span>SS892268</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-name">
        <div data-element="patient-last-name"><p class="p-link">DemoCardio</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-small">
        <div id="ember2312" data-element="patient-dob" class="ember-view"><div class="visible-xs visible-sm">03/15/1943</div>
<div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">Mar 15, 1943</div>
</div>
        <div data-element="patient-gender">Male</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-contact">
        <div data-element="patient-address" class="ellipses" title="47 Peach Lane, Atlanta, GA 30032">47 Peach Lane, Atlanta, GA 30032</div>
        <div data-element="patient-phone-numbers" class="ellipses">
            <span id="ember2313" title="(555) 555-5555" class="ember-view phone-number"><span class="p-666">M </span>
<span>(555) 555-5555</span></span>
            <span id="ember2314" title="(555) 555-5555" class="ember-view phone-number"><span class="p-666">H </span>
<span>(555) 555-5555</span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-small text-right" data-element="patient-last-accessed">
        <div>10:51 PM</div>
        <div>04/17/18</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>


</div><div id="ember2243" class="ember-view vertical-item" style="min-height: 76px;">                          <div id="ember2315" class="ember-view row-patient list-item"><div class="col-pic"><img id="ember2316" src="assets/images/default_profile-51d6b94248e500ae7f03bc28a8110e4d.png" class="ember-view"></div>
<div class="row" data-guid="327fca40-c7b9-40af-ac77-83d6d8989372">
    <div class="col-name">
        <div data-element="patient-first-name"><p class="p-link">Nancy <!----><!----></p></div>
        <div data-element="patient-record-number" class="prn"><span class="p-666">PRN </span><span>NO731672</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-name">
        <div data-element="patient-last-name"><p class="p-link">DemoObstetrics</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-small">
        <div id="ember2317" data-element="patient-dob" class="ember-view"><div class="visible-xs visible-sm">04/08/1982</div>
<div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">Apr 08, 1982</div>
</div>
        <div data-element="patient-gender">Female</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-contact">
        <div data-element="patient-address" class="ellipses" title="321 S. 54th St, Anytown, NY 12345">321 S. 54th St, Anytown, NY 12345</div>
        <div data-element="patient-phone-numbers" class="ellipses">
            <span id="ember2318" title="(555) 555-5555" class="ember-view phone-number"><span class="p-666">M </span>
<span>(555) 555-5555</span></span>
            <span id="ember2319" title="(555) 555-5555" class="ember-view phone-number"><span class="p-666">H </span>
<span>(555) 555-5555</span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-small text-right" data-element="patient-last-accessed">
        <div>10:51 PM</div>
        <div>04/17/18</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>


</div><div id="ember2244" class="ember-view vertical-item" style="min-height: 76px;">                          <div id="ember2320" class="ember-view row-patient list-item"><div class="col-pic"><img id="ember2321" src="assets/images/default_profile-51d6b94248e500ae7f03bc28a8110e4d.png" class="ember-view"></div>
<div class="row" data-guid="04cf0c5b-805b-4478-a6a9-744b9e4d1c18">
    <div class="col-name">
        <div data-element="patient-first-name"><p class="p-link">Brenda <!----><!----></p></div>
        <div data-element="patient-record-number" class="prn"><span class="p-666">PRN </span><span>BO958186</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-name">
        <div data-element="patient-last-name"><p class="p-link">DemoOncology</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-small">
        <div id="ember2322" data-element="patient-dob" class="ember-view"><div class="visible-xs visible-sm">07/15/1951</div>
<div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">Jul 15, 1951</div>
</div>
        <div data-element="patient-gender">Female</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-contact">
        <div data-element="patient-address" class="ellipses" title="4700 Milword Drive, Stony Brook, NY 11790">4700 Milword Drive, Stony Brook, NY 11790</div>
        <div data-element="patient-phone-numbers" class="ellipses">
            <span id="ember2323" title="(555) 555-5555" class="ember-view phone-number"><span class="p-666">M </span>
<span>(555) 555-5555</span></span>
            <span id="ember2324" title="(555) 555-5555" class="ember-view phone-number"><span class="p-666">H </span>
<span>(555) 555-5555</span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-small text-right" data-element="patient-last-accessed">
        <div>10:51 PM</div>
        <div>04/17/18</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>


</div><div id="ember2245" class="ember-view vertical-item" style="min-height: 76px;">                          <div id="ember2325" class="ember-view row-patient list-item"><div class="col-pic"><img id="ember2326" src="assets/images/default_profile-51d6b94248e500ae7f03bc28a8110e4d.png" class="ember-view"></div>
<div class="row" data-guid="a221f6e9-dacf-4b1c-86cc-2712be3231fd">
    <div class="col-name">
        <div data-element="patient-first-name"><p class="p-link">John <!----><!----></p></div>
        <div data-element="patient-record-number" class="prn"><span class="p-666">PRN </span><span>DP278077</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-name">
        <div data-element="patient-last-name"><p class="p-link">DemoPrimaryCare</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-small">
        <div id="ember2327" data-element="patient-dob" class="ember-view"><div class="visible-xs visible-sm">03/30/1977</div>
<div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">Mar 30, 1977</div>
</div>
        <div data-element="patient-gender">Male</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-contact">
        <div data-element="patient-address" class="ellipses" title="4994 Shady Range, Ossawinamakee Beach, MS 39469">4994 Shady Range, Ossawinamakee Beach, MS 39469</div>
        <div data-element="patient-phone-numbers" class="ellipses">
            <span id="ember2328" title="(555) 555-5555" class="ember-view phone-number"><span class="p-666">M </span>
<span>(555) 555-5555</span></span>
            <span id="ember2329" title="(555) 555-5555" class="ember-view phone-number"><span class="p-666">H </span>
<span>(555) 555-5555</span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-small text-right" data-element="patient-last-accessed">
        <div>10:51 PM</div>
        <div>04/17/18</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>


</div><div id="ember2246" class="ember-view vertical-item" style="min-height: 76px;">                          <div id="ember2330" class="ember-view row-patient list-item"><div class="col-pic"><img id="ember2331" src="assets/images/default_profile-51d6b94248e500ae7f03bc28a8110e4d.png" class="ember-view"></div>
<div class="row" data-guid="64cd540e-2482-49dc-9b68-952ff38e995d">
    <div class="col-name">
        <div data-element="patient-first-name"><p class="p-link">Jaclyn M<!----></p></div>
        <div data-element="patient-record-number" class="prn"><span class="p-666">PRN </span><span>JE742116</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-name">
        <div data-element="patient-last-name"><p class="p-link">DemoENT</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-small">
        <div id="ember2332" data-element="patient-dob" class="ember-view"><div class="visible-xs visible-sm">10/21/1985</div>
<div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">Oct 21, 1985</div>
</div>
        <div data-element="patient-gender">Female</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-contact">
        <div data-element="patient-address" class="ellipses" title="323 Elast Drive, Brownsville, PA 49300">323 Elast Drive, Brownsville, PA 49300</div>
        <div data-element="patient-phone-numbers" class="ellipses">
            <span id="ember2333" title="(555) 555-5555" class="ember-view phone-number"><span class="p-666">M </span>
<span>(555) 555-5555</span></span>
            <span id="ember2334" title="(555) 555-5555" class="ember-view phone-number"><span class="p-666">H </span>
<span>(555) 555-5555</span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-small text-right" data-element="patient-last-accessed">
        <div>10:51 PM</div>
        <div>04/17/18</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>


</div><div id="ember2247" class="ember-view vertical-item" style="min-height: 76px;">                          <div id="ember2335" class="ember-view row-patient list-item"><div class="col-pic"><img id="ember2336" src="assets/images/default_profile-51d6b94248e500ae7f03bc28a8110e4d.png" class="ember-view"></div>
<div class="row" data-guid="f7ab7035-26f3-44d5-9b24-a44c8e8b62e9">
    <div class="col-name">
        <div data-element="patient-first-name"><p class="p-link">Shana <!----><!----></p></div>
        <div data-element="patient-record-number" class="prn"><span class="p-666">PRN </span><span>SP708107</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-name">
        <div data-element="patient-last-name"><p class="p-link">DemoPeds</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-small">
        <div id="ember2337" data-element="patient-dob" class="ember-view"><div class="visible-xs visible-sm">11/08/2005</div>
<div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">Nov 08, 2005</div>
</div>
        <div data-element="patient-gender">Female</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-contact">
        <div data-element="patient-address" class="ellipses" title="488 Taylor St, San Francisco, CA">488 Taylor St, San Francisco, CA</div>
        <div data-element="patient-phone-numbers" class="ellipses">
            <span id="ember2338" title="(555) 555-5555" class="ember-view phone-number"><span class="p-666">M </span>
<span>(555) 555-5555</span></span>
            <span id="ember2339" title="(555) 555-5555" class="ember-view phone-number"><span class="p-666">H </span>
<span>(555) 555-5555</span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-small text-right" data-element="patient-last-accessed">
        <div>10:51 PM</div>
        <div>04/17/18</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>


</div></vertical-collection>
```

It seems long but I find that 'id="ember2185"' contains all the element in the table, and for each row, they all have the classname "ember-view vertical-item", that's why I use class name to grab all the rows. However, it does not work, error message is

```
"Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted
  (Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.181)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.551581 (2c9c29527ada10af4745ab26dd000ebb6d5e055e),platform=Mac OS X 10.11.6 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/invalid_selector_exception.html
Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:33:15.31Z'
System info: host: 'JiandeMacBook-Pro.local', ip: '2601:547:900:384f:0:0:0:6b7c', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.11.6', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, acceptSslCerts: false, applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false, browserName: chrome, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 2.38.551581 (2c9c29527ada10..., userDataDir: /var/folders/l1/4syvs2451pq...}, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: false, handlesAlerts: true, hasTouchScreen: false, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, mobileEmulationEnabled: false, nativeEvents: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: MAC, platformName: MAC, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, takesHeapSnapshot: true, takesScreenshot: true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour: , unhandledPromptBehavior: , version: 65.0.3325.181, webStorageEnabled: true}
Session ID: a9aaa265d0cf9f9e96d5072cfbfca7ee"
```

So what is wrong? How can I click each row in a table? Thanks for your help!

Comment: If the exception is on `By.classname`, try another selector such as `By.xpath("//div[@class='ember-view vertical-item']")` or `By.cssselector`

Comment: IMO, the question `I would like to click each name() under the col "first name"` is too broad. Narrow down the question to a specific requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to fetch the first name, then check with the below xpath selector.

```
String firstName = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//vertical-collection[@class='ember-view']/div[1]//*[@data-element='patient-first-name']")).getText();
```

The `div[1]` specified in the selector will change, now in the above xpath it will take the first name of the first data. I think its Cindy. 
So you can iterate using a loop to get all the values.

Sample code for getting the total count in the table and first name is shown below,

```
int number = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//vertical-collection[@class='ember-view']/div//*[@data-element='patient-first-name']")).size();
    System.out.println("Count is : "+number);

    for(int i=1;i<number;i++){
        String firstName = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//vertical-collection[@class='ember-view']/div["+i+"]//*[@data-element='patient-first-name']")).getText();
        System.out.println("First name : "+ firstName);
    }
```

Output:

```
Count is : 12
First name : Cindy
First name : Michelle
First name : Eric
First name : Jennifer
First name : Michael T
First name : Eric R
First name : Steve
First name : Nancy
First name : Brenda
First name : John
First name : Jaclyn M
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, I am able to click each first name now. Also, how could you know the xpath? I am not familiar with it, and the only way I know is to find the first name element and copy xpath in chrome inspect. But when I paste it, I found it is "//*[@id="ember4019"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]" for Cindy. It is different from what you give me, so you write it yourself?

Comment: @Coolboy It is better to write the selectors by yourself. Recording or just inspecting the values are not recommended to use in Real time scenarios. Make use of **firebug ** and **firepath ** in Mozilla. In that you can check by changing the values. I think both Firebug and Firepath supports only in the versions older than 50 of Mozilla. The  Also you can use inspect element and write your own selectors in Console of Chrome and Mozilla.

Comment: @Coolboy   May be the following link would be helpful reference for starting to write your own locators. [Locators using Firebug and Firepath](http://www.software-testing-tutorials-automation.com/2015/07/steps-to-get-element-xpathcss-using.html)

Comment: thanks,man. So xpath from firebug and firepath is different from xpath from Chrome Inspect? I mean now I just use inspect in the Chrome and choose "copy xpath" and get xpath. So it is not as precise as the result from firebug? Thanks for your patience!

Comment: @Coolboy  When you inspect and copy the locator from the Chrome you will be getting the xpath which will be containing all nodes. Like all the div present until the actual element. But if you are customizing the xpath means you can directly give the class name to the path. Check the link [Write dynamic xpath](https://www.softwaretestingmaterial.com/dynamic-xpath-in-selenium/)